# Django reverse foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I'm using python/django for 1 month now and I need help because I can't find any similar questions that has the answer I was looking for. I have Worker model and Job model. A Worker can have many jobs. I need to query the latest job that the Worker has.

```py
class Worker(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Job(models.Model):
   worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   position = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   start_date = models.DateField()
```

I am currently using this sample code. The problem is that this returns similar Worker objects including its previous jobs. I just want to query the Worker with the latest job location and start date.

```py
for employee in Job.objects.all():
   print(employee.worker, employee.location, employee.start_date)
```

Sample Output

```
(A, north, 2018-01-21)
(A, south, 2018-09-13)
(A, east, 2019-05-11)
(B, west, 2019-01-01)
```

Is there a way to use a for loop to a query like `Worker.job_set.all()` to have this expected output

```
(A, east, 2019-05-11)
(B, west, 2019-01-01)
```

Hope you can help a newbie like me. Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform ordering on the job_set queryset, for example. Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
for worker in Worker.objects.all():
     latest_job = worker.job_set.latest('start_date')
     print(worker.name, latest_job.location, latest_job.start_date)
```

Comment: Fix your typo, its `worker.job_set.latest` the extra `()` causes an error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other two answers are very simplistic. Both of them are tackling the problem you are trying to accomplish now, but these solutions will fail once you have more and more workers/jobs since all their solutions are O(N*N). This solution is O(N).

```
    subqry = models.Subquery(Job.objects.filter(worker_id=models.OuterRef('worker_id'))
                                        .order_by('-start_date').values('id')[:1])
    workers = Worker.objects.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('job_set',
                                                              queryset=Job.objects.filter(id__in=subqry)))

    for worker in workers:
        # no matter what this will always have 1 // or nothing, depending on your logic; if nothing, fix this.
        latest_job = list(worker.job_set.all())[0]  
        print(worker.name, latest_job.location, latest_job.start_date)
```

This will do a single query for `Worker` like the rest, BUT will only do a single query for the latest jobs, the other solutions will make a query PER worker, this is inefficient and slow.

See this example for more background as how i tested all this. https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/ac2ada9c27196fc90c1b75f2d01a6271#file-django_prefetch_limit-py-L163

Comment: You're right that you can get orders of magnitude better performance by reducing the operation into a single SQL query. But the database still has to do the work, and I'm pretty sure O(1) is impossible.

Comment: @HåkenLid check my tests, its O(1). The load on the database is minimal compared to making a query per worker. This will make 2 queries, no matter how many `Worker`s/`Job`s you have.

Comment: @HåkenLid notice the number of queries https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/ac2ada9c27196fc90c1b75f2d01a6271#file-django_prefetch_limit-py-L233-L234 this is O(1)

Comment: I am using python2.7 and I think this only works on python3 because when I am trying to import it on shell, it raises an error *cannot import name Subquery*. But thanks for the solution, I might study it for future

Comment: @dahyunism I'm guessing you're on django < 1.11? Just a friendly reminder, anything bellow 1.11 is officially unsupported. https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions and support of 1.11 will be dropped jan 1, 2020 along with python 2.7 -- i humbly suggest you upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @HåkenLid you are right, O(1) for this problem is impossible, it is O(N). Reading this website showed me how foolish i was https://cooervo.github.io/Algorithms-DataStructures-BigONotation/big-O-notation.html

Comment: Cool. I didn't want to start a discussion about it in the comments, since it's not super relevant to the original question. In any case, your solution is faster, because the relational database management system performs query operations much much faster than juggling data around in django/python. Even if the algorthmic complexity is the same in big O, in practice there can be a huge difference between two implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `last` method on the filtered and ordered (by `start_date`, in ascending order) queryset of a worker.

For example, if the name of the worker is `foobar`, you can do:

```
Job.objects.filter(worker__name='foobar').order_by('start_date').last()
```

this will give you the last `Job` (based on `start_date`) of the worker named `foobar`.

FWIW you can also get the `first` element if you're sorting in the descending order of `start_date`:

```
Job.objects.filter(worker__name='foobar').order_by('-start_date').first()
```